# Setting a property value by reflection from DataGridView value

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I've a DataGridView, and I want to change collection who connect to this list when cell value has been changed, using `CellEndEdit` event:

```
var p = wareList[e.RowIndex].GetType().GetProperties()[e.ColumnIndex];

object value = dataGreadView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value;

p.SetValue(typeof(Ware), Convert.ChangeType(value, p.PropertyType));
```

But at the last line I got exeption `System.Reflection.TargetException: "The object does not match the end type."`

Answer (score 0):

`SetValue()` takes the object to set the value on.

Your property is not defined on `System.Type`, so passing a `System.Type` gives an error.

You need to pass an object that actually has your property.

Comment: I'm little confused... for example, I have the `Ware.Name` prop with `string` type, so if `p = Ware.Name` that I thinked I can pass  `p.PropertyType` and it will return `string` type for my `Ware.Name` prop... or no?

Comment: @NisuSan: That has nothing to do with `SetValue`, which wants an instance, not a type.